# SQL statement with native R object

Tags: r, oracle

I am using an Oracle SQL database, which I am querying from R. Is it possible to query the Oracle DB using native R objects in the statement, for example to join a DB table to a dataframe?

Setting `where` conditions works nicely from R like so:

```
oraConnect::load_from_db(sprintf('select * from dual where DUMMY = %s', 'X'))
```

Is it possible, for example, to join a DB data table to an R data table like so (does not work as written) by inserting an R object into an oracle SQL statement?:

```
testdf = data.frame(DUMMY = 'X')
oraConnect::load_from_db(sprintf('select DUMMY from dual join %s rdf on dual.DUMMY = rdf.DUMMY', testdf))
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to use the `glue` package IMHO. I use this when connecting via the DBI and odbc packages and pass SQL directly using the `dbGetQuery` function

Comment: @MDEWITT thanks for the suggestion. Do you have an example to hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer does not use the `oraConnect` package, but can be used to connect to Oracle databases as long as you have an odbc connection set-up on your machine.

### Connecting

First load the packages and connect to the database

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 'YOUR_DSN')
```

After you have your connection set, you can do a quick test query. I use the SendQuery, Fetch, and Clear. You don't have to do this, but it avoids some of the conflicts etc and makes dealing with bigger data pulls easier. Note that "schema_name" is the schema name in your database if required.

```
query <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM schema_name.table WHERE ROWNUM <= 10")
out <- DBI::dbFetch(query)
DBI::dbClearResult(query)
```

The `out` object will have your data.

### Autogenerating Queries

Now this is where I will use the `glue` package

```
library(glue)

dat  <- c("apples", "pears", "oranges")

(my_new_query <- glue("SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = {dat}"))

# SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = apples
# SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = pears
# SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = oranges
```

Or something like

```
table_1 <- "cities"
table_2 <- "states"

(my_new_query <- glue("SELECT a.* FROM schema_name.{table_1} LEFT JOIN schema_name.{table_2} ON..."))

#SELECT a.* FROM schema_name.cities LEFT JOIN schema_name.states ON...
```

Which you could then submit to your database

```
query <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, my_new_query)
out <- DBI::dbFetch(query)
DBI::dbClearResult(query)
```

You can also add things within the `glue` statements like making a list.

```
dat  <- c("apples", "pears", "oranges")

(my_new_query <- glue("SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = IN({glue_collapse(dat, sep = ',')})"))

#SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = IN(apples,pears,oranges)
```

thus everything can be extended.